I see strange faces
As I walk, people go past me.  I see their faces. Weird faces.
I've heard of blue eyes and red noses. Those are fine.
But green foreheads?
Yellow cheeks?
Indigo lips?
Orange hair?
Violet chins?
What kind of a world am I in?

Are the specific colors always related to the body parts to the right of the them, or can they for example have yellow hair or indigo chins too?

Answer uncertain.

Actually, I'll say yes. Any colour anywhere.  Blue noses. Violet eyes. Whatever.

You're in

 a wonderful world.

 The colors of the rainbow
 so pretty in the sky
 are also on the faces
 of people going by.


(I previously wrote a similar question.)

Are you perhaps inside the world of

 Cubism?  The paintings have weird looking faces and can contain all kind of colors.  Here is an example of an artwork of Picasso, called "The Weeping Woman":


No, but a nice guess.
